# External Sharing of Folders in SharePoint Online using REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, odata, sharepoint-online

I am new to SharePoint Online and REST API.

I am currently working on a **SharePoint Add-In which creates folders in a document library residing in the Host Web and share the permission to specified external users**. I am currently attempting to do everything using **REST API**.

I am successfully able to create the folders but I am currently **unable to share the folders to external users**.

I am having trouble **resolving the following endpoints when attempting to use the host web context**. The first endpoint below is for resolving the external email, and the second one is for performing the actual sharing of the folder to the external user.

```
[appUrl]/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerResolveUser?@target='[hostUrl]'

[appUrl]/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/SP.Web.ShareObject?@target='[hostUrl]'
```

I am getting the error `404 Not Found`: `Cannot find resource for the request SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplerPickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerResoveUser`. The same error occurs for `SP.Web.ShareObject` when I try to force it to run.

Below is the javascript that I am using

```
var ShareToRecipients = function(folder, recipient, appUrl, hostUrl){

var url = appUrl = "/_api/SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerResolveUser";
url = WebComponents().getTargetUrl(url, hostUrl);

var sharedDocUrl = hostUrl + "/ExternalShareDocLib/" + foldername;

var checkUser = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'queryParams': {
            "__metadata": {'type': "SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters"},
            "AllowEmailAddresses": true,
            "AllowMultipleEntities": false,
            "AllUrlZones": false,
            "MaximumEntitySuggestions": 50,
            "PrincipalSource": 15,
            "PrincipalType": 1,
            "QueryString": recipient
        }
    }),
    headers:{
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        myapp.LogAPIError(jqXHR, textStatus)
    }
});

checkUser.success(function(data){
    var user = data.d.ClientPeoplePickerResolveUser;
    var result = JSON.parse(users);

    if(users !== undefined){
        var reqUrl = appUrl + "/_api/SP.Web.ShareObject";
        reqUrl = WebComponents().getTargetUrl(reqUrl, hostUrl);

        var shareCall = $.ajax({
            url: reqUrl,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "url": reqUrl,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "url": sharedDocUrl,
                    "peoplePickerInput": '[' + user + ']',
                    "roleValue": "1073741827",
                    "groupId": 0,
                    "propagateAcl": false,
                    "sendEmail": true,
                    "includeAnonymousLinkInEmail": true,
                    "emailSubject": "A document folder has been shared to you",
                    "emailBody": "A document folder has been shared to you. The folder name is " + folder                       
                })
            });
        });

        shareCall.success(function(data){
            myApp.LogInformation("Successfully shared " + folder + " to " + recipient);
        });

        shareCall.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            myApp.LogAPIError(jqXHR, textStatus);
        });
    }       
});}
```

For generating the Host URL Endpoint

```
var WebComponents = function(){
var getTargeturl = function (url, hostUrl){
    if(hostUrl){
        var api = "_api/";

        var index = url.indexOf(api);
        url = url.slice(0, index + api.length)+
        "SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +
        url.slice(index + api.length);

        var connector = "?";
        if(url.indexOf("?") > -1 && url.indexOf("$") > -1){
            connector = "&";
        }

        url = url + connector + "@target='" + hostUrl + "'";
    }

    return url;
}

return{
    getTargeturl: getTargeturl
}}
```

Can you help verify if I am using the endpoints correctly and if what I am trying to do is even possible?
Appreciate the help.

Cheers,
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my resolution just in case anyone else encounters this issue.
I was able to use the API by:

1. Removing `url = WebComponents().getTargetUrl(url, hostUrl)`
   and `reqUrl = WebComponents().getTargetUrl(reqUrl, hostUrl)`.
2. Giving the App **Full Control** in the **Tenant** via the **AppManifest.xml**